# Why is my NUnit Assert failing when deploying to Azure?

Tags: unit-testing, azure, msbuild, continuous-integration, nunit

I have a test project I'm using to practice deploying to Azure

Located:
https://github.com/EdLichtman/HelloAzureCI

When I use Resharper to run the NUnit tests, All of them pass except for the Environment-Specific test case, as should be expected.

However when I run deploy.cmd on my local computer All 4 tests fail because "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

One of my unit tests is "Assert.AreEqual(1,1)" and that throws a nullReference exception, which leads me to think that Assert is not an instance of an object.

Why is this such a problem? Can anyone else recreate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few odd things here, but the main one is that you are trying to run NUnit 3.7.1 tests using an NUnit V2 console runner (2.6.2). This is never going to work. My suggestion is that whenever you have trouble with running NUnit in a remote environment or using a third-party runner, you fall back to using the console runner locally. Even if that's not your preferred mode of working, you will usually be able to figure out what's wrong more easily if you eliminate as many middlemen as possible.

If you actually want to run under vsconsole, then you need to install the nunit3-vs-adapter nuget package and point to it's location in your command-line. Note that the adapter, even though it is ours, constitutes another middleman, so debugging using nunit3-console is still a good choice.

Comment: So are you suggesting that I run a command from net35 instead of vs.console.exe? Which command should I point to it's location from?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure WHAT you're suggesting, (you could be suggesting the solution I ended up with) but because of what you said about the TestAdapter, I added a .runsettings file to the end of vs.console.exe command by adding /Settings: "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\.runsettings" and pointed to the adapters in TestAdapterPaths. I'm still having trouble with Azure environment issues, but on my local machine I got the tests to pass! Thanks!

Comment: The project you linked has a reference to NUnit 3.7.1 framework.
The output indicates you are running the NUnit 2.6.2 console.
There is no way that any NUnit V2 console runner (2.0-2.6.4) can execute tests correctly that are built against the NUnit 3.0 or higher framework.

Comment: Sorry, and I realized I miscommunicated -- and I think I figured out what you were suggesting -- I added the /TestAdapterPath: to the running of the vstest.console.exe. Meanwhile I'm still getting an error because on my local environment only 4 tests run. On Azure my tests run twice. Once with the adapter and once without. Same code, so I'm not running the tests twice in code. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Well, I used the NUnit.ConsoleRunner -3.7.0 .exe and it works. I still have no idea why the tests are running twice but I have automated deploy!